# Using UNION and GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP for two separate queries

Tags: mysql, aggregate, union, rollup

I am querying current and archived invoices and using UNION to combine the results into one table. I'm using GROUP BY to control how the individual invoice lines (ii and iai) are summed.
I then need to add in subtotals for groups of the unified data, so have tried to use a GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT ih.ref, ih.invno, SUM(ii.val) AS 'val_'
    FROM ih, sl, ii
    WHERE ii.invno = ih.invno AND ih.ref = sl.ref
    GROUP BY ii.invno   

    UNION
    SELECT iha.ref, iha.invno, SUM(iai.val) AS 'val_'
    FROM iha, sl, iai
    WHERE iai.invno = iha.invno AND iha.ref = sl.ref
    GROUP BY iai.invno
)AS A
GROUP BY 1,2 WITH ROLLUP
```

The problem is that the resulting data isn't correctly totalling values on the aggregate lines.

| ref | invno | val_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | 10450 | 210.42 |
| AA1 | 10451 | 102.45 |
| AA1 | NULL | 102.45 |
| BB2 | 12532 | 128.94 |
| BB2 | NULL | 128.94 |
| CC3 | 28011 | 166.67 |
| CC3 | 48823 | 54.00 |
| CC3 | 52521 | 11.40 |
| CC3 | NULL | 11.40 |
| NULL | NULL | 11.40 |

The val_ column isn't showing a subtotal in the NULL rows created from the ROLLUP. This works if I only query with the one select statement of invoices, instead of querying 2 with a union.
It's clearly an issue due to using both UNION and GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP, but how can I query both data sets, with summed figures, and still get aggregate rows with totalled values?

Comment: You should break the habit of using the old `comma operator` and use `JOIN`s with the join criteria placed in the `ON` clause. It makes more complex queries easier to read and understand, with filtering criteria in the `WHERE` clause and `JOIN` criteria in their respective `ON` clauses. Mixing the old `comma operator` and `JOIN` syntax can lead to issues due to [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html#:~:text=the%20precedence%20of%20the%20comma%20operator%20is%20less%20than%20that). You should probably be using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.